# Strange behavior of neo4j-service on Debian 8.1

Tags: neo4j, debian

I have installed neo4j on Debian 8.1 thanks to these instructions : http://debian.neo4j.org/

Now if, as root, I start neo4j with neo4j-service like this

```
service neo4j-service start
```

Sometimes it will works correctly but most of the the time, the neo4j-service will timeout. But the interesting fact is that neo4j is indeed started, I can go the the browser and make some queries. But the neo4j-service tells me that it failed :

```
root@ns***:~# service neo4j-service start
Job for neo4j-service.service failed. See 'systemctl status neo4j-service.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
root@ns***:~# systemctl status neo4j-service.service
● neo4j-service.service - LSB: Neo4j Graph Database server
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/neo4j-service)
 Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Fri 2015-10-16 19:03:08 CEST; 6min ago
Process: 24556 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/neo4j-service stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 29730 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/neo4j-service start (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Oct 16 18:58:08 ns***.ip-91-***-***.eu neo4j-service[29730]: WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Oct 16 18:58:08 ns***.ip-91-***-***.eu neo4j-service[29730]: Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
Oct 16 19:03:08 ns***.ip-91-***-***.eu systemd[1]: neo4j-service.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Oct 16 19:03:08 ns***.ip-91-***-***.eu systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Neo4j Graph Database server.
Oct 16 19:03:08 ns***.ip-91-***-***.eu systemd[1]: Unit neo4j-service.service entered failed state.
```

And sometimes it will tell me that the service started correctly but will not manage to stop it.
Most of the time, I have to kill the process myself to "reset everything" correctly.

Do you know why this is happening ?
Are you aware of any issues with the neo4j-service on Debian 8.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach to running Neo4j is deprecated and you should use neo4j command.

Or you can write your own service wrapper and for that I suggest to you use http://supervisord.org/

Comment: Thanks, after all I used a systemd service to launch and stop neo4j.  
Works like a charm!